# Respecting global options in knitr

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I am having trouble with setting global options in my R Markdown documents. A simple example follows. In this case I've attempted to set `global.par = TRUE`. The expectation is that any `par()` specifications I make in one chuck are carried into subsequent chunks. However, this is not happening.

````
```{r package_options, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_knit$set(global.par = TRUE)
```

```{r}
lambda <- 0.2; n <- 1000
exp <- rexp(n, lambda)
par(cex = 0.7)
hist(exp)
```

```{r}
lambda <- 0.02; n <- 1000
exp <- rexp(n, lambda)
hist(exp)
```
````

Specs: Max OS 10.11, R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16), RStudio 0.98.1062, knitr 1.12.3

Comment: Weird. I can reproduce this for setting `cex`, but setting `bg` or `mar` works.

Comment: Agree, so far the problem appears to affect `cex`. I'll add others if more are found.

Comment: Turns out that `cex` is a different animal. I just fixed it in knitr. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue has been [fixed](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/24344832b8b352bac0a97cca54b4ccc6b4232d60) in **knitr** (>= v1.12.17), and you may test the current [development version of **knitr**](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#installation) on Github. I just discovered that setting `mfcol`/`mfrow` will reset `cex` to 1, and that was the root cause of **knitr** not being able to restore `cex` correctly.

Comment: Confirmed, that fixes the bug. But is it really a good idea to [prohibit changing `usr`](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/24344832b8b352bac0a97cca54b4ccc6b4232d60#diff-04f9cbb0662e7b2fe9b767a43c0e7d8cR332)? Who sets this parameter should be aware of that he/she is doing. And if they want to shoot themselves in the foot ...

Comment: As usual, you know these details in knitr very well. However, the problem is that there is no way to detect if the user has intentionally changed `par(usr)` in a code chunk. `usr` is always set to new values whenever you draw new plots. Try to run `str(par('usr')); plot(1:10); str(par('usr')); plot(rnorm(100)); str(par('usr'))` and you will see it. I think it should be rare that users want to set `usr`, so I just removed it from the parameters.