# global.par = TRUE not working in knitr for bg in RSweave doc

Tags: r, graphics, global-variables, knitr, rnw

I need to change the background of all tiff images produced by my R Sweave document and encountered the same problem as described here:

[Respecting global options in knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606445/respecting-global-options-in-knitr)

but with par(bg = ), which supposedly is working according to a comment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<setup, cache = FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(dev = c('pdf','tiff'))
opts_knit$set(global.par = TRUE)
par(bg='cyan')
@

<<>>=
plot (3,3)
@

\end{document}
```

(I'm not allowed to comment or I would have stayed on that post.)

I also tried using a hook, based on the example here:
https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-graphics.Rnw

```
knit_hooks$set(par=function(before, options, envir){
if (before) par(bg='cyan')
})
```

but that didn't work either.

The only thing that works is to set the parameter in every chunk, for example:

```
<<test, dev = 'tiff'>>=
par(bg = 'cyan')
plot(3,2)
@
```

(I actually want a white background but it's easier to test with a color. Not my choice to use TIFF btw.)

Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: Please add a reproducible example where `global.par` doesn't work for `bg`. On your hook: Did you "activate" the hook, i.e. did you use `par = TRUE` as chunk option?

Comment: No, that's it! I didn't activate the hook! Thank you!!! (I'm including the example for global.par anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MWE presented does not imply that `global.par` doesn't work for `bg`. The reason why the plot doesn't use the specified background color is that `global.par = TRUE` affects only the *subsequent* chunks.

> Knitr's settings must be set in a chunk before any chunks which rely on those settings to be active. [[source](http://yihui.name/knitr/objects/)]

**You cannot rely on a global option to be apply in the chunk you set it.**

The following example demonstrates that setting the background color in a later chunk makes the plot use it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<setup, cache = FALSE>>=
opts_knit$set(global.par = TRUE)
@

<<>>=
par(bg='cyan')
@

<<>>=
plot (3,3)
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: Aha. That works. Many, many thanks! (I upvoted the answer but it doesn't view publicly.)